# Speed up self join in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, inner-join

I have a table of connections between different objects and I'm basically trying a graph traversal using self joins.
My table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `connections` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sourceId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `targetId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `weight` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `refId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ts` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sourcetype` (`type`,`sourceId`,`targetId`),
  KEY `targettype` (`type`,`targetId`,`sourceId`),
  KEY `complete` (`dId`,`sourceId`,`targetId`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The table contains about 3M entries (~1K of type 1, 1M of type 2, and 2M of type 3).

The queries over 2 or 3 hops are actually quite fast (of course it takes a while to receive all the results), but getting the count of a query for 3 hops is terribly slow (> 30s).

Here's the query (which returns 2M):

```
SELECT
  count(*)
FROM
  `connections` AS `t0`
JOIN
  `connections` AS `t1` ON `t1`.`targetid`=`t0`.`sourceid`
JOIN
  `connections` AS `t2` ON `t2`.`targetid`=`t1`.`sourceid`
WHERE
  `t2`.dId = 1
  AND
  `t2`.`sourceid` = 1
  AND
  `t2`.`type` = 1
  AND
  `t1`.`type` = 2
  AND
  `t0`.`type` = 3;
```

Here's the corresponding EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys                   key         key_len  ref                         rows  Extra  
1   SIMPLE       t2     ref   targettype,complete,sourcetype  complete    16       const,const                  100  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE       t1     ref   targettype,sourcetype           targettype   8       const                       2964  Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE       t0     ref   targettype,sourcetype           sourcetype  16       const,travtest.t1.targetId  2964  Using index
```

Edit: Here is the EXPLAIN after adding and index to `type`:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys                        key         key_len  ref                         rows  Extra     
1   SIMPLE       t2     ref   type,complete,sourcetype,targettype  complete    16       const,const                 100   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE       t1     ref   type,sourcetype,targettype           sourcetype  16       const,travtest.t2.targetId    2   Using index
1   SIMPLE       t0     ref   type,sourcetype,targettype           sourcetype  16       const,travtest.t1.targetId    2   Using index
```

Is there a way to improve this?

2nd edit:

```
EXPLAN EXTENDED:
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                       | key        | key_len | ref                        | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref  | type,complete,sourcetype,targettype | complete   | 16      | const,const                |  100 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref  | type,sourcetype,targettype          | sourcetype | 16      | const,travtest.t2.targetId |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t0    | ref  | type,sourcetype,targettype          | sourcetype | 16      | const,travtest.t1.targetId |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------+------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+

SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                    |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select count(0) AS `count(*)` from `travtest`.`connections` `t0`            |
|       |      | join `travtest`.`connections` `t1` join `travtest`.`connections` `t2`                      |
|       |      | where ((`travtest`.`t0`.`sourceId` = `travtest`.`t1`.`targetId`) and                       |
|       |      | (`travtest`.`t1`.`sourceId` = `travtest`.`t2`.`targetId`) and (`travtest`.`t0`.`type` = 3) |
|       |      | and (`travtest`.`t1`.`type` = 2) and (`travtest`.`t2`.`type` = 1) and                      |
|       |      | (`travtest`.`t2`.`sourceId` = 1) and (`travtest`.`t2`.`dId` = 1))                          |
+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: did you try an additional index on just column `type` alone?

Comment: Additional index? I think I'd start by removing those that you have. keep the PK (obviously) and add an index on (did,source_id,type). But, I should add that I'm definitely no expert when it comes to this - I adopt the 'suck it and see' approach!

Comment: That seems to help a lot. 2.4s is much better. Though according to EXPLAIN that index is not used.

Comment: @Strawberry: Unfortunately that index doesn't improve the query time. I already tried several indices, but so far none have improved the time like the `type` index does.

Comment: @Martin Walker besides the,`type` index, the usefulness of which should be clear looking at your `where` clause, I would also suggest a `sourceId` (by itself) index to help the join condition between t0 and t1; eventually also a `targetId` index, with probably less improvement. Remove the others

Comment: @guido I just tried that but actually with my current indices the query is about twice as fast. As I said before, the `type` index isn't used at all, so I'm baffled that the query time improved

Comment: @Martin Walter query cache maybe? Would you update your explain?

Comment: @guido I updated my question. Looks like the query now uses a different index for the first join, I wonder why

Comment: @giammin That doesn't make any difference

Comment: @MartinWalter did you try my answer?

Comment: @MartinWalter this is interesting; before the `type index`, which is not used, for table `t1` the optimizer was just using part of the `targettype` index, now it decide to use `sourcetype`, also for the join with `t2`. Would you also post the output of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` followed by 'SHOW WARNINGS`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html

Comment: thanks; I am guessing: you have the `innodb_stats_on_metadata` turned off, the cardinality of the indexes were wrong; after adding the `type` index the key distribution was recomputed (like executing `ANALYZE TABLE`) and the optimizer chose a different (better) plan thanks to this added informations. I f this is the case, you can try dropping the `type` key, nothing should change.

Comment: That seems plausible. I just checked and since 5.6.6 that setting is off by default. And I did notice that the query uses different indices after I changed something (adding or removing indices), while not using the changed indices.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index for `sourceid`,`targetid`and `type` columns then try with this query:

```
SELECT
  count(*)
FROM
  `connections` AS `t0`
JOIN
  `connections` AS `t1` ON `t1`.`targetid`=`t0`.`sourceid` and `t1`.`type` = 2
JOIN
  `connections` AS `t2` ON `t2`.`targetid`=`t1`.`sourceid` and `t2`.dId = 1 AND `t2`.`sourceid` = 1 AND `t2`.`type` = 1
WHERE
  `t0`.`type` = 3;
```

-------UPDATE-----

I think that those indices are right and with those big tables you reached the best optimization you can have. I don't think you can improve this query with other optimization like table partitioning/sharding.

You could implement some kind of caching if those data does not change often or the only way I see is to scale vertically

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The times are almost identical to my query when I use your indeices + query (+/- 200 ms)

Comment: @MartinWalter then I think that you don't have any choice then to scale vertically your sql server...

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'm also beginning to think that I'm already at the maximum. Caching seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you are handling graph data, am i right?

Your 3 hop query has a little chance to optimize. It is bushy tree. A lot of connections made. I think JOIN order and INDEX is right.

EXPLAIN tells me t2 produce about 100 targetId. If you get rid of t2 from join and add   `t1.sourceId IN (100 targetId)`. This will take same time with 3 times self join.

But what about break down 100 target to 10 sub IN list.  If this reduce response time, with multi thread run 10 queries at once.

MySQL has no parallel feafure. So you do your self.

And did you tried graph databases like jena, sesame? I  am not sure graph datdabase is faster than MYSQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, that is a graph. I'm currently trying different databases, among them Neo4j. So far I am not impressed by the speed of it. Breaking the query into different subqueries might be a way, but I would rather have a more generic approach.

Comment: @MartinWalter I wrote some information for you, new answer but not The solution you want. sorry bothering you if you don't want to that and my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer. just FYI.

If MySQL or the other DBs is slow for you, You can implement your own graph database. then this paper `Literature Survey of Graph Databases`[1] is a nice work on Graph Database. surveyed several Graph Database, let us know many technique.

`SCALABLE SEMANTIC WEB DATA MANAGEMENT USING VERTICAL PARTITIONING` [2]  introduce vertical partitioning but, your 3M edges is not big, vertical partitioning can't help you. [2] introduces another concept `Materialized Path Expressions`. I think this can help you.

[1] http://www.systap.com/pubs/graph_databases.pdf

[2] http://db.csail.mit.edu/projects/cstore/abadirdf.pdf

Comment: @MartinWalter, did you ever figure this out? We are doing something similar with coercing MySQL to do a graph db. Our self joins are taking a LONG time to fetch record sets, since they are pretty large. We only have 2-hops in our tree traversal...

Comment: @horcle_buzz sorry, we abandoned the idea for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You comment that your query returns 2M (assuming you mean 2 million) is that the final count, or just that its going through the 2 million.  Your query appears to be specifically looking for a single T2.ID, Source AND Type joined TO the other tables, but starting with connection 0.

I would drop your existing indexes and have the following so the engine does not try to use the others and cause confusion in how it joins.  Also, by having the target ID in both (as you already had) means these will be covering indexes and the engine does not have to go to the actual raw data on the page to confirm any other criteria or pull values from.

The only index is based on your ultimate criteria as in the T2 by the source, type and ID.  Since the targetID (part of the index) is the source of the next in the daisy-chain, you are using the same index for source and type going up the chain.  No confusion on any indexes

INDEX ON (sourceId, `type`, dId, targetid )

I would try by reversing to what hopefully would be the smallest set and working OUT... Something like

```
SELECT
      COUNT(*)
   FROM
      `connections` t2
         JOIN `connections` t1
            ON t2.targetID = t1.sourceid
            AND t1.`type` = 2
            JOIN `connections` t0
               ON t1.targetid = t0.sourceid
               AND t0.`type` = 3
   where
          t2.sourceid = 1
      AND t2.type = 1
      AND t2.dID = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the query currently returns 2 million results. Of course that is only test data at the moment, the actual data might be much larger. Your suggestions don't change the query time very much, I'm beginning to think the optimizer is already doing a good job.